# php and mysql issue with the date datatype

Tags: php, mysql

We are creating the functionality where we use filter in the front-end with a search. when the user click on the filter, the search box will open and with have couple drop-down options like starts with, equal to and ends with.

MY issue is the date is saved in YYYY-mm-dd in the database as date datatype( mysql) and in the front-end we have search options like starts with, ends with and equal to and it works perfectly fine when we search for " starts with = 2013 "

But we have one more options where the user can change the format to " dd-mm-yyyy" in the settings page and when we search "starts with =20" it should give us the date starting with 20 and not year starting with 20.

Comment: Thanks for sharing.  Did you have a question, or were just giving a report on the current status of your development efforts? You might consider making use of some of the MySQL builtin date and time functions, such as `DATE_FORMAT()`, `DAY()`, etc. [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: What can you do? Change the DB field to something more generic, use DB function, transform the input data in the front end, transform the search data in the back end.

Answer (score 1):

An simple solution I see is that you could create a second column where the date is just in the other format. You could automate that with code instead of having to enter each date again.

Else, you could reverse the format of their setting back to the YY-mm-dd, but if you care about only days and ignore the months and years, you could match with a regex expression the last "dd" in your actual YY-mm-dd (like using the percent "%" and the like operator in mysql).
E.g, the "=" is replaced by LIKE and there is a percent before the day "20" to exclude characters before and  :

```
SELECT *
FROM employees 
WHERE (date_yyy_mm_dd LIKE '%20' OR date_yyy_mm_dd LIKE '%21' OR date_yyy_mm_dd LIKE '%22' OR [...] OR date_yyy_mm_dd LIKE '%31')
```

more info on : http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-like/

An other solution I see is that you could fetch all the results without worrying about the date, then manipulate the dates and reverse them and then put all that into an huge array. Then search back only the dates ranges you need in that array and you'll can loop what rest in it to print the results...

Hope it helps you.